# New Guitar Sound Check

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

I have just brought a new Acoustic Guitar. I found that String sounds metallic is this normal ? 
Will my Guitar Sound improves gradually i.e Playing become smooth  ?

Currently sliding the finger or changes chord in guitar also produces a metallic sound

Comment: New strings generally do sound more 'jangky' than those that have been 'played in'. Other strings are available - flatwound, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very likely due to different strings than on your reference guitar, that you may have in mind. Factors like material, coating, winding technique, gauges all influence the sound. Maybe experiment with different string sets to find the sound you like.

New strings sound more crisp than older ones. With some materials this effect is more pronounced.

Answer (score 0):

The natural sound of a particular manufacture and type of strings often needs to be matched up with a particular manufacture and type of guitar to achieve the most pleasing sound. This process gets complicated by the personal preference of the sound produced by matching these things up. Everybody has his own preference, but you should understand that a wooden body on a guitar will have a very difficult time producing a metallic sound without the use of a resonator, so I personally would suspect the problem to be with the strings being used.